# pagination in symfony 4 using KnpPaginatorBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1, symfony4

Attempted to load class "`KnpPaginatorBundle`" from namespace "`App\Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle`". Did you forget a "`use`" statement for "`Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle`"?

[image: Controller image]

[image: Kernel image]

[image: Service image]

[image: Index image]

Comment: Image links? No thanks.  Tagging a question with 2.1 and 4?  Rather unusual.  The error message itself tells you exactly what it wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: sorry i just start symfony one week so i use the use statement but nothing change if you could check the images to see my controller and other pages

Comment: Does clicking on randomly posted images seem like a good idea to you?

Comment: My guess the problem is in config/bundles.php, because this is the only place I can think of from the top of my head where you would reference the `KnpPaginatorBundle`-class. If that is not the case, search in your src/ folder where you use the class `KnpPaginatorBundle` and check if the the use statement is in the list at the top of the file.

Comment: no not really but when we use KnpPaginatorBundle we use the same classes so i tried to show the code that i used its same in the KnpPaginatorBundle instructions any way the images not the problem the problem is paginatin sir

Comment: thank you dbrumann i checked your solution but still the smae problem.            did you use the  KnpPaginatorBundle before under symfony 4 ?

Comment: can you show us contents of your `bundles.php` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is create a new archive `paginator.yaml`

```
//config/paginator.yaml
knp_paginator:
  page_range: 5                      # rango por defecto de paginas en los controles del paginador
  default_options:
    page_name: page                # nombre del parámetro de la URL para la página
    sort_field_name: sort          # nombre del parámetro de la URL para la ordenación
    sort_direction_name: direction # nombre del parámetro de la URL para la dirección(ASC o DESC)
    distinct: true                 # Garantizar resultados distintos
  template:
    pagination: '@KnpPaginator/Pagination/sliding.html.twig'  # plantilla controles
    sortable: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link.html.twig # plantilla links ordenación
```

After in the Controller add `extends Controller` in the class

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Entity\Usuario;
use App\Form\UsuarioType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

/**
 * @Route("/admin/usuarios")
 */
class BackendController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="admin")
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $usuarios = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Usuario::class)
            ->findAll();
        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $usuarios, $request->query->getInt('page', 1), 20);

        return $this->render('backend/usuario/index.html.twig',
            array('pagination' => $pagination));

    }
```

Finally add this in the `archive.yml`

```
<div class="navigation">
  {{ knp_pagination_render(pagination) }}
</div>
```

Reference: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/issues/468#issuecomment-356580135

Comment: It works without create archive.yml that you didn't say where we need to add it. Of course help full page : https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle

Answer (score 1):

Just add class namespace of `KnpPaginatorBundle`:

in `config/bundles.php`:

```
<?php

return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    ***************************************************************
    ***************************************************************
    Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle::class => ['all' => true]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add your Bundle in the Kernel , exactly in `config/bundles.php`

```
Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle::class => ['all' => true]
```

Comment: in Symfony4 new bundles are automatically added in config file !